# CSS second menu, falls under the menu instead of under each category

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie here and have used this resource as a search function, but today I am stumped and want to seek advice and options.

Here is my site.

http://www56.myfantasyleague.com/2016/home/77769

The second menu that starts with the word MANAGEMENT, I would like to change the mouse over hover from the 1px dotted line, to mimic this action from the CBS site mouse over top left, show here

http://www.cbssports.com/collegebasketball/ncaa-tournament/brackets/viewable_men

If you mouse over the TOP LEFT corner **NCAABB**>> CBS SPORTS HOME, FANTASY, ETC, you see that light blue transition under each category...

I would like to have that function, replace my 1px dot bottom border. When I add this code, it captures the entire block of the nav menu instead of the link names.

```
ul.quicknav > li > a::before {
  background-color: #3987d9;
  content: "";
  height: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  transition: height 0.2s ease 0s;
}

ul.quicknav li a:hover::before {
  height: 6px;
}
```

Would someone be able to help me achieve this by editing this css code? Hopefully it is something easy, and not something where I have to div tag or class tag the menu bar per each link...

Thank you!
Sticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be missing a `display: block;` in your `ul.quicknav > li > a::before`. And if you're using `position: absolute;`, don't forget to add `position: relative;` to the parent (`ul.quicknav > li > a`, in this instance).

Alternatively, you could use `box-shadow` on the `ul.quicknav > li > a` instead of using a pseudo element.

```
ul.quicknav > li > a{
    box-shadow: #3987d9 0 0 0 0;
    transition: box-shadow .2s;
    -webkit-transition:box-shadow .2s; // Don't forget the -webkit- version...
}

ul.quicknav > li > a:hover{
    box-shadow: #3987d9 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

Your code already has a transition set (`transition: color 0.6s ease-in 0s;`) so you could adapt that like this: `transition: color, box-shadow 0.6s ease-in 0s;`.

---

Here's a quick example to show the two different methods: http://codepen.io/tomhazledine/pen/KzWLzY

The `box-shadow` option needs much less code.

Comment: Hey Tom, so after reading this reply I realize I would need to add a class to the menu <li> to get this css to work with "before"... so trying your method on the drop shadow seems to be a quick fix, however after adding it to my site above, the drop of the underscore seems to be instant, rather than a smooth trans drop down..... can we fix that?    Ironically when it retracts- it draws back up smoothly..

Comment: Hey DA-G-GURU, looks like you have a `transition: color 0.6s ease-in 0s;` rule on the *hover* as well (`.quicknav li a:hover {`).  If you remove that, the transition is smooth in as well as out. Cheers.

Comment: Tom... Yo Da Man.. you can see the demo is working now on this drop shadow method, and I realize I have a few options to achieve this effect also, which is always nice to know.  I appreciate your HELP, and I have 2 more questions: First is it possible to award you help points and close this thread? 2. And I didn't get an email of your first reply, I simply checked the thread out, where is the setting to be email on replies?  TY

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Looking good on your demo! You should be able to up-vote my answer and mark it as the "approved answer" using the controls  next to the top-left corner of my answer.

Comment: As for email-setting, I think that's controlled in your profile's settings (link in the header, then click the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab.

Comment: I have checked boxed approved answer, if that wasn't it let me know. In settings-profile, I seen to uptick my email to every 3 hours and checked that box. Seems like I would see something that reads get notified instantly via email...oh well...   Tom your help with the code pen options and different code options was "outstanding"... it always is the little things that go the distance. - Job well done

Comment: Perfect - it's the "green tick" I'm after. If you hit the up-arrow it gives me extra rep-points, too ;) Happy to help, and glad we were able to get the effect you were after.

Comment: Tom- Just one more question.. If I wanted to keep the transaction of the color fade on "hover" as I had it before, then I guess I would have to ditch this drop shadow option and run with adding a class to the <li> and then using the *before* coding?  Not a big deal, I am just a curious person lol

Comment: Try `transition: color 0.6s ease-in 0s,box-shadow .2s;`. That should let you use both at once. (untested)

Comment: Tom that code worked well thanks! I have one more need, I added this code to the second tier of links that start with LINKS-CALENDAR-ACTIVITY-LOGIN and it works well.....however it DONT work in IE or EDGE.....as the first part of code you did does.......anyway to make this work in all browsers for the second tier links?

Comment: Hey Tom started a new topic on this, as I don't know if you can see the replies..